# How to make random walk stationary?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, random-walk

I know that random walk is modeled as;     $Y_t = Y_{t-1}+ u_t$ ;
It is known that it is not a stationary model since the variance of observations at different times are not same. As a general, remedy difference (integration) is taken to solve it,hence make it stationary.

I come up with the idea that it might be done it two way;

one that;

$Y_t - Y_{t-1}= Y_{t-1}+ u_t - Y_{t-1}$

$Y_{t-1}$ can be substracted in both handsides. In this way indeed we can have a stationary time series with the help of the assumption that $u_t$ is a white noise.

I have seen that difference is also can be applied in a way that (I-L)(I refers for identity, and L for Lag operator). In this case;

$(I-L)Y_t= (I-L)Y_{t-1}+ (I-L)u_t$  => $\Delta Y_t = \Delta Y_{t-1} + u_t$

In this case, if we try to take covariance of $Y_{t-1}$ we see that it is not constant, hence thestochastic process is not stationary.

I feel like the latter derivation is wrong, since differincing does not end up with a stationary time-series. BUT, I couldnt find where I am mistaken.

I need your help to understand my mistake. Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: In the last equation / implication, you get $(I-L)u_t=u_t$ which is not correct.

Comment: Could you please explain me why? I thought subtracting a random variable from a random variable would end up being a random variable again..

Comment: Aren't $L$ and $I$ defined as $L[u_t]=u_{t-1}$ and $I[u_t] = u_t$?

Comment: $(I-L)u_t=u_t-u_{t-1}\neq u_t$ unless $u_{t-1}=(0,\dots,0)$, and usually you would not assume the latter to hold.

Comment: While $u_t$ is a random variable, "$u_t$" is not shorthand for "a random variable"; this $u_t$ has some specific properties that aren't all invariant to differencing (such as independence of $u_t$ and $u_s$ for $s\neq t$.

Comment: (At least I presume the $u$'s are independent here, you should be clear about what all your variables are.) The argument would go something like: Start with

$$Y_t=Y_{t-1}+u_t,\qquad (1)$$

where $u_t$ has the following properties (....).
Differencing $Y_t$:

$(I-L)Y_t = Y_t-Y_{t-1}$. From $(1)$,  $Y_t-Y_{t-1}=u_t$. Hence a differenced $Y_t$ is $u_t$, so $(I-L)Y_t$ has the following properties (....)